# App crashes when calling uri.getLastPathSegment()

Tags: java, android

My application always crashes after the camera takes a photo and the user exits the camera. Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private ImageView imageView;

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            progress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
            progress.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progress.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Finished...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post here your Logcat, what error you are getting

Comment: Is data.getData () null is that the error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.jurge.cameraupload.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:61)

Comment: sorry about that...trying to send a print screen but could not figure out how it works as I am new to stackover

Comment: Make a new file and pass the uri from the file to the intent then in the result you will already have the uri. Theres a whole process to it. Setting up a fileprovider and other stuff

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: so you suggest doing this with bitmap?

Comment: There is no `Uri`, which is why you are crashing. Right now, your code is set up to get the image via `intent.getParcelableExtra("data")`, which gives you a thumbnail-sized `Bitmap`. If you want a full-sized image, add `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, to indicate where the camera app should write that image. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Camera/FileProvider) for how to use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: So how should I write my code @CommonsWare? thanks

Comment: I do not know if you want a thumbnail or a full-sized photo. If you want a thumbnail, save the thumbnail `Bitmap` to some file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) and upload that. If you want a full-sized photo, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: I want a full size photo

Comment: I have searched for EXTRA_OUTPUT but got confused on where to include it

Comment: I am trying this but seems that it does not work

Comment: intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);